# DynamoDB locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Im trying to run dynamoDB locally in Ubuntu. I have done everything as here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html
If I want to check if my database works locally:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Im getting:

```
alexa@alexa-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/DynamoDB$ aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

Why? I dont want to use AWS. I thought I can be able to test locally dynamodb without AWS account. Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Despite the fact you're hitting a local endpoint that doesn't require credentials the aws cli tool you're using to interact with the dynamoDB-local still looks for values for the expected AWS credentials to sign your requests with.

This is what the final point in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html is trying to suggest. If you set dummy values for `AWS Access Key ID`, `AWS Secret Access Key` and set a default region by running `aws configure` as suggested you should be able to successfully run commands against your dynamoDB-local instance.

[This page on configuring the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-quick-configuration) gives more details on what's going on behind the scenes here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to save credentials so that aws cli tool can interact with dynamoDB.
You have to save credentials at `nano ~/.aws/credentials`

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = **************
aws_secret_access_key = *******************
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the aws credentials as given in below link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: <your dummy key>
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: <your dummy password>
Default region name [None]: region-name e.g. us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

Comment: For me (using python) the missing steps were - installing the awscli package, then running the command 'aws configure' in terminal. You then get prompted to add the values as shown by @P3arl